# create json in android

Tags: android, json

I wish to create json looking like:

```
{"man": 
   {
   "name":"emil",
   "username":"emil111",
   "age":"111" 
   }
}
```

within android. This is what I have so far:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
json.put("name", "emil"); 
json.put("username", "emil111"); 
json.put("age", "111");
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("name", "emil");
        json.put("username", "emil111"); json.put("age", "111");

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can put another JSON object inside the main JSON object:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
JSONObject manJson = new JSONObject();
manJson.put("name", "emil");
manJson.put("username", "emil111");
manJson.put("age", "111");
json.put("man",manJson);
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more then just putting the answer there !

Comment: Unfortunately, I see only 
{"man": 
   {
   "age":"111" 
   }
}

Am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, **json object** can be created lie this

```
    val jsonObject = JSONObject()

    val manObject = JSONObject()
    manObject.put("name", "emil")
    manObject.put("username", "emil111")
    manObject.put("age", "111")

    jsonObject.put("man", manObject)
    Log.d("MIK", jsonObject.toString())
```

Output would look like this

```
{"man":{"name":"emil","username":"emil111","age":"111"}}
```