# Create a JSON file in android

Tags: android, json, path

In my app I will create a JSON file that contains this kind of information:

```
{
   "sites":{
      "site":[
         {
            "src":"/Users/redoddity/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/EE5BB071-A217-4C8D-99BA-5B6F392889A6/Documents/Sito3.html",
            "name":"Sito3",
            "expiryDate":"29 Ago 2013"
         },
         {
            "src":"/Users/redoddity/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/EE5BB071-A217-4C8D-99BA-5B6F392889A6/Documents/Sito2.html",
            "name":"Sito2",
            "expiryDate":"29 Ago 2013"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

(this is the JSON I create for the iPhone app). Now I need to create a JSON file for the Android app.

First question:  how I can create a JSON in Android, on here I found this: [create json in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706046/create-json-in-android), but this will create a JSON without array (you can see in my JSON I've an array of site)?

Second question: you can see that in my JSON there are the path of the html file I downloaded in the Documents folder of iPhone, now in Android I stored the html with this code:

```
File file = getFileStreamPath(titleText + ".html");
    if (!file.exists()) {
          try {
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(titleText + ".html", 0));
        out.write(html);
        out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
          Log.d("FILE", "Il file esiste");
          alert.show();
}
```

How I can know the path where this file are stored?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use getFileStreamPath

```
File file = getFileStreamPath(titleText + ".html");
```

From the doc

> Returns the absolute path on the filesystem where a file created with
>   openFileOutput(String, int) is stored.

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
root.put("key",(Object)arr);
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for answering the second question I made, what about the first, how I can do a JSON with an array inside it?

Comment: what`s the matter about it? Android has its own library to create json in a simpler way

Comment: I added an example. As you can see it is really simple to compose complex json objects

Answer (score 0):

I use this method to create JSON in Android, with an inner array of data, with some metadata outside the array. I'm sure you can hack it to fit.

```
    public final static JSONObject writeListJSON(ArrayList aGroupedList,
        String username) throws Exception {

    ArrayList aList = (ArrayList) aGroupedList.get(0);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        String sub_id = (String) aList.get(14);

        obj.put("username",
                URLEncoder.encode(BtoCryptex.btoEncrypt(username), "UTF-8"));
        obj.put("proj_id", "BT");
        obj.put("inner_count", "" + aGroupedList.size());
        obj.put("device", android.os.Build.MODEL);
        obj.put("version", android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
        obj.put("protocol_id",
                URLEncoder.encode((String) aList.get(13), "UTF-8"));
        obj.put("date", URLEncoder.encode((String) aList.get(2), "UTF-8"));
        obj.put("time", URLEncoder.encode((String) aList.get(10), "UTF-8"));
        obj.put("endtime",
                URLEncoder.encode((String) aList.get(15), "UTF-8"));
        obj.put("complete",
                URLEncoder.encode((String) aList.get(16), "UTF-8"));
        obj.put("placename",
                URLEncoder.encode((String) aList.get(4), "UTF-8"));
        obj.put("gridref",
                URLEncoder.encode((String) aList.get(5), "UTF-8"));
        obj.put("sub_id", URLEncoder.encode(sub_id, "UTF-8"));
        for (int i = 0; i < aGroupedList.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject innerobj = new JSONObject();
            ArrayList bList = (ArrayList) aGroupedList.get(i);
            innerobj.put("species_name",
                    URLEncoder.encode((String) bList.get(3), "UTF-8"));
            innerobj.put("count",
                    URLEncoder.encode((String) bList.get(6), "UTF-8"));
            innerobj.put("breed",
                    URLEncoder.encode((String) bList.get(7), "UTF-8"));
            innerobj.put("sensitive",
                    URLEncoder.encode((String) bList.get(9), "UTF-8"));
            innerobj.put("comment",
                    URLEncoder.encode((String) bList.get(11), "UTF-8"));
            obj.put("INNER" + (i + 1), innerobj);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // System.out.println(obj.toString());
    return obj;
}
```